# Cannot add multiple select2 option dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2, multiple-select

[image]In my web application I am using select2 multiple select box. Also i use autocomplete feature of select2. When the api retrieve data, i want to append data to multiple select2 as options. But i faced with some weird problems. It does not append options properly. Here is my code.

It is  js code

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.select2').select2({
            dataType: 'json',
            delay: 250,
            ajax: {
                url: '/Message/GetSelect2Options',
                dataType: 'json',
                processResults: function (data) {
                    newOption = new Option(data.results[0].groupName, data.results[0].messageGroupId);
                    $('.select2').append(newOption).trigger('change');
                    return {
                        results: data.results
                    };
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: "_But i faced with some weird problems._" What problems? Please post full details as much possible when asking a question.

Comment: @palaѕн i have updated the question and added picture

Comment: @palaѕн i know that i can loop and append. I wanted to test that and wrote without loop. The problem is it is not appended like option. When I append it just appends at bottom like text

Comment: Yes, I have updated the code to fix that. You just need to loop through each `data.results` array and return data as `id` & `text` format.

Comment: Looks like you're missing the select2 css (or have it in the wrong order) - can you add a snippet to your question to demonstrate the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to loop through each `.select2` class using the [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) method, and then append the options separately to each single `.select2` element like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.select2').each(function() {
      $(this).select2({
         dataType: 'json',
         delay: 250,
         ajax: {
            url: '/Message/GetSelect2Options',
            dataType: 'json',
            processResults: function(data) {
               return {
                  results: $.map(data.results, function(obj, index) {
                     return { id: obj.messageGroupId, text: obj.groupName };
                  })
               };
            }
         }
      });
   })
});
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/5qmuaojz/)